# SetCurrentDirectory to a path with dot at the end

Tags: winapi

Win32 SetCurrentDirectory() function failing to change current directory to a path with dot at the end, resulting GetLastError 2 (The system cannot find the file specified.).

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

File names are not allowed to end in dots, and the behaviour is not guaranteed if they do.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions

> Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although
>   the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell
>   and user interface does not.

Comment: So strange, but how windows embedded file explorer able to change directory to one with dot at the end?

Comment: I don't know - maybe it's not actually calling `SetCurrentDirectory`. Possibly using the short name might work. It's a bad idea either way.